# Is it possible to have a Chromium browser inside of a plugin?

Tags: c++, plugins, chromium, embedded-browser

I'm trying to embed a chromium browser into my C++ plugin, which will be run inside of a host application. This is my first time working with chromium, so please forgive my ignorance.

I've got the program running to the point where cef is initialized and the browser is instantiated with no asserts or issues. However, the browser gets stuck loading things. I've noticed that during the instantiation of the browser, the host application raises an error about misused command line arguments. Is chromium trying to receive messages from the command line? If so, how can I receive those messages when my application is a plugin?

I can reproduce the host application's error by calling it from the command line with unknown arguments (Ex. "C:/HostApplication.exe -someRandomString").

Comment: running an external program via exec()-type calls is about as much a plugin as a rabid wolverine in your living room is a "house guest".

Comment: I don't have any intention of running external programs, I've just noticed that CEF seems to cause this error while instantiating the browser. This leads me to believe that it is passing some kind of arguments to my executable via command line. I'm wondering if there is something I can do in my setup that will give CEF another method of communication.

Comment: You probably don't want the complete browser inside your plugin. Instead look at the [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) browser engine (which is used by Chromium and others).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why do you say I don't need the whole browser? What does CEF have that I wouldn't want to embed into my application?

Comment: I believe I've figured out what is going on here. 

Chromium is trying to spawn new thread processes from the command line. It's trying to start up a copy of the current process, which in the case of a plugin points to host application.

To show this, I set the `settings.single_process` flag to true. The browser (very slowly) instantiated, and I could see google. Unfortunately, it was completely unusably slow when collapsed down to one thread, pretty much as expected. I'm not sure where to proceed from here, but at least I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Chrome Frame" is very close to what you're describing: https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

The good news is, chrome frame, like the rest of Chromium project is open source, so check out the source: http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome_frame/